# Javascript arrays of enums

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, enums

Given an array of objects (greetings) containing enumerated name-value pairs:

```
const greetings = []
greetings.EN = {
  HELLO:  'Hello',
  BYE:    'Goodbye',
  SCRAM:  'Get lost'
}
greetings.ES = {
  HELLO:  'Hola',
  BYE:    'Asta luega',
  SCRAM:  'Vete'
}
greetings.FR = {
  HELLO:  'Bonjour',
  BYE:    'Au revoir',
  SCRAM:  'Allez-vous en'
}
```

The only way I can access an item is i.e.

```
console.log(greetings.EN.BYE)
```

Which can be implemented in 3 switch statements, one per language type see [codepen](https://codepen.io/wb2wrf/pen/LYYrVGr?editors=0011)

Rather than 3 switch statements, I would prefer use access an item with a syntax like :

```
let language = 'EN'
console.log(greetings.language.BYE)
```

which would allow me to directly access the translations without having to use the switch statements
However, this produces a compiler error.
Is there a way to resolve these values at run time?

Comment: If you want to use a string as a key name, use this syntax `greetings[language].BYE`

Comment: Also, don't use non numeric keys with arrays ... Use an object instead

Comment: bracket notation and should be `const greetings = {}` not []

Comment: There is [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for these sort of things... I recommend starting by reading a [general guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction) before diving into [references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) though if you're not familiar with basic language features like property accessor notation.